# Common ways to pay for a room in the U.S.?

Tags: usa, rental, payment

I plan to stay in the U.S. next year. In my country it is common to pay rent and these things by wire transfer (so you transfer the money from your account to the landlord's account online.) Is this also the most common way to do it in the U.S.? What payment options do I have to expect there?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I fail to see the exact link to Travel.

Comment: Moving to the USA from South Africa, I found the American banking system to be kinda stone-age. The paper check is still king here ... The only thing which comes close to the convenient electronic banking I'm used to is PayPal.

Comment: @brhans Your comment is a perfect example of why people fail to realize just how large and varied the US is: no one in my area uses paper checks

Comment: @CGCampbell - Maybe you just don't see them. I live in the south-east and bank with a major US bank. For some of my "online" account payments they will still print & mail a paper check to a company I owe instead of doing an electronic transfer. I am also unable to initiate an electronic transfer myself if I wanted to make a personal payment to you using your bank routing code & account number. My wife is British and she also can't understand the apparent 'archaicness' of American banking. If your banking experience is different I'd be genuinely interested to find out who you bank with ...

Answer (score 2):

To this day many landlords will ask for a check and if you are going to stay for a long time you surely will have an SSN and open a bank account and can provide a check. If not, you can get a money order at post offices, convenience stores, major grocery stores and many banks for $1 to $2. Most people will accept it. Wire transfer doesn't exist for mere mortals.

Comment: US bank account holders really have no way to send money electronically to other accounts?

Comment: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/51730/tenant-wants-to-pay-rent-with-eft . I've rented in the US without a SSN. Was quite a few years ago though and paid by cheque.

Comment: @Calchas That is correct.  US and Canada finance systems are highly retarded, even worse than UK.

Comment: Wow. Doesn't that make the likes of online banking pretty pointless?

Comment: @CMaster it is actually fairly common to pay by electronic transfer but only regular bills like phone, utilities, credit card, where you can say to your bank "pay to my account number X at company Y" or, if the company is set up for it, you tell them "take the money from acct number X at bank Y." The second is essentially the same as giving them a check. We don't typically give our account numbers to people who want to *pay* us, however.

Comment: In many cases I've seen "pay to my account number X at company Y" get translated by the bank into "print a paper check and mail it to company Y" when making bill payments from their online banking system.

Comment: My landlord uses a web-based system where I can pay by electronic funds transfer from my bank account (or they'll take a paper check). That's with a larger commercial landlord who pays for the system. Smaller landlords who are just people renting out a few rooms are, in my experience, likely to only accept checks and may not use use any technology more advanced than a shoebox to keep track of their finances.

Comment: @phoog As the _recipient_ of such bill payments, I can tell you that what actually happens is that the sending bank mails a check!

Comment: @MichaelHampton often, but not always.  In my case, there are certain payees who get electronic transfers.

Comment: @phoog Good point. Not every bank is still in the 19th century...

Comment: @brhans in many cases, yes, that's true.  True electronic transfers seem to be possible only with certain high-volume payees like utility companies and credit cards.  At least that's the case at my bank.

Comment: @ZachLipton most likely your landlord is using ACH payments, in which you have authorized the landlord to submit the electronic equivalent of a check drawn on your account.  In Europe, for example, you would instead send your landlord's account number to *your* bank with instructions to transfer the money.  The ACH system requires you to trust the landlord to withdraw the correct amount; in the European system, *you* control the transfer yourself.

Comment: @phoog Exactly. It's a pull system here and not a push system. Which is stupid, but we all know that. ACH payments in the US come from the conversion of checks to electronic payments. Me giving my landlord my account number for an ACH payment is practically no different (there are some legal differences) than me giving them a check and them converting the check to an electronic payment. While we're complaining, we can discuss the fact that ACH payments still take days and days to process despite this being 2016.